# Rudin 3.26 3.29

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to go through the theorems and proofs in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. As of now I hope I could get some clarifications as I'm stumbled upon some concepts used or rather trivial details in the theorem 3.26 and 3.29.

Here's the theorem 3.26:

> If 0 $\le$ x $\lt$ 1, then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$ If x $\ge$ 1, the series diverge.

The proof is:

> If x $\neq$ 1, $$s_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ The result follows if we let n $\to$ $\infty$...

Here I'm confused how Rudin came up with the result $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

As for theorem 3.29, my confusion lies in its proposition, but I will lay out the theorem and the proof just in case.

Here's theorem 3.29:

> If p $\gt$ 1, $$(10) \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(logn)^p}$$ converges; if p $\le$ 1, the series diverges. 
>  Remark: "log n" denotes the logarithm of n to the base e.

The proof is:

> The monoticity of the logarithmic function implies that {log n} increases. Hence {1/n log n} decreases and we can apply theorem 3.27 to (10). This leads us to the series $$(11) \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \frac{1}{2^k(log 2^k)^p} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k log 2)^p} = \frac{1}{(log 2)^p} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}$$ and theorem 3.29 follows from 3.28.
>  
>  This procedure may evidently be continued. For instance, $$(12) \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n log n log log n}$$ diverges, whereas $$(13) \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n log n (log log n)^2}$$ converges.

For reference, theorem 3.27:

> Suppose $a_1$ $\ge$ $a_2$ $\ge$ $a_3$ $\ge$...$\ge$ 0. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k} = a_1 + 2a_2 + 4a_4 + 8a_8 + ...$$ converges.

And theorem 3.28:

> $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges if p $\gt$ 1 and diverges if p $\le$ 1.

I'm having trouble to prove divergence of (12) and convergence of (13) by myself. So far, my proof for (12) is

> Since {1/n logn log logn} decreases so we can apply theorem 3.27. Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \frac{1}{2^klog2^klog log2^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{log2^k log log2^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{klog2 log(klog2)}$$

And from here I don't know how to proceed. I don't know how to deal with $log(klog2)$. Same thing happened for (13). Thanks if you read this through!

Comment: Just use 3.27 again.

Comment: for the first series, note that $s_{n+1} = 1 + xs_n$. now look at the difference $s_{n+1}-s_n$

Comment: In 3.26, it should be $\rm s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}n}x^k$, which is a geometric progression and equals $\rm \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ if $\rm x\ne 1$.

Comment: Hint for (12): Note that $\rm \log(k\log 2)=\log k+\log(\log 2)\le \log k+\log k$, for large $k$.

Comment: @Koro I still could not figure (12) out. I assume your hint implies using comparison test. But how do we find the convergence/divergence of $\frac{1}{logk + logk}$?

Comment: For reference, Theorem 3.27 is called the Cauchy Condensation Test.

Comment: Write `$\log n$` and not `$log n$` to get $\log n$ and not $log n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to your work for $(12)$, if it is shown that$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k\log2 \log(k\log2)}$ converges (or diverges), then so does the original series in $(12)$.

Using the hint in comments, note that there exists a $K$ such that for all $k\ge K$, the following happens: $$\frac{1}{k\log2 \log(k\log2)}\ge \frac 1{k\log2(2\log k)}\tag 1$$

Now, note that the series $\sum_{n\gt 1} \frac 1{(2\log 2) n\log n}$ diverges by theorem $3.27$ and therefore by comparison test in $(1)$ and remark in the first para, it follows that the series in $(12)$ diverges.